# Push non-angular object to AngularJs controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a Angular controller that have a FormData scope, e.g: $scope.FormData. Data is collected via model connected to a simple form. Also, I have an external non-angular js code on the page. I need to push one of its variables to $scope.FormData.name. How can I do that? Already tried acces it as a global variable via $window, but no luck. Here is the example code:

Angular code:

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.formData.day = "1";
        $scope.formData.month = "January"; ...
```

And non-angular code:

```
var data = [{data1: value1}, {data2:value2}];
```

Binding this data to a model in a form is not a good option, because this is an object, so, I will get a string in a formData, like [Object, Object].

Comment: I think you will need to create a module factory that return this value and inject it in the controller. What exatly the other js file is ?

Comment: The other file is gmaps.js library. I am trying to push markers object into the scope.

Comment: don't separate them, run your maps code from inside a directive

Comment: If it's a global var and your gmaps.js is included before angular, you have just to use the var.
Like the jsfiddle I created for you : http://jsfiddle.net/thomasleduc/HB7LU/6847/

Comment: Thanks, guys! Merging the external code with angular controller did the trick. Question resolved.